# Keep alive of TCP connection

Tags: c#, tcp

Добрый день.

У нас на работе с коллегой возник спор по поводу keep alive TCP соединения с клиентом.

Я утверждаю:

Метод

```
Stream.Read (Byte[], Int32, Int32)
```

Read возвращает 0 только в том случае, если нет дополнительных данных в потоке и больше не ожидаются (например, сокет закрыт или достигнут конец файла)

(копия примечания с msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Т.е. если мы выполняем await ReadAsync и постоянно получаем 0 байт, следовательно TCP клиент отвалился.
Данный метод "keep alive" актуален при использовании ReadAsync и корректном дисконнекте клиента (чтобы на уровне TCP успел придти пакет о закрытии сокета).

Мой коллега утверждает:

Нельзя пологаться на этот метод.
Единственный способ "keep alive" - это послать "heart bit" и удостовериться, что на том конце есть кому его принимать, иначе TCP клиент отвалился.

Хотелось бы узнать что думаете вы??

Comment: Оффтопик: вы случайно не один из старых участников? У вас знакомый ник.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, противоречия между тем, что вы говорите, и тем, что говорит ваш коллега, нет. Если вернулся 0, то тогда да, чтение окончено. Но если клиент отвалился, и система об этом не знает, то вызов будет висеть вечно. Или если система узнает об этом, то вызов наверняка завершится с исключением (в этом последнем не уверен на 100%). Так что по идее оба правы.

Comment: Недавно у нас было обсуждение этого же вопроса, и если мне не изменяет память, кто-то раскопал, что Keep-Alive-timeout у TCP под Windows около 2-х часов (!), и его не так-то просто изменить.

Comment: На самом деле, если клиент отвалился (корректно), то ReadAsync будет возвращать 0, и не будет останавливаться в await. Но если клиент всё ещё подключен, то будет ожидать байты

Comment: Под «отвалился» я имел в виду «отвалился по таймауту», сорри. Ну или «упал сервер», «порвался кабель», ... То есть, отвалился, не закрыв корректно соединение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет смысла "постоянно получать 0 байт", первый же 0 означает закрытый на чтение сокет.

Однако, закрытым соединение становится только после прихода FIN или RST-пакета, причем пакет RST еще и имеет негарантированную доставку! Поэтому, если вас не устраивает системный тайм-аут в 2 часа для Keep-Alive (который к тому же по умолчанию для сокетов выключен) - обязательно нужно писать свою логику определения зависших соединений.

Тем не менее, не обязательно для этого отправлять heartbeat-сообщения. Если протокол подразумевает возможность повторного подключения - можно просто выставить тайм-аут на чтение и после тайм-аута закрывать соединение.

С другой стороны, надо помнить о NAT. Многие реализации PNAT имеют свои тайм-ауты для исходящих соединений - и могут разорвать неактивное соединение. Этот тайм-аут может быть очень небольшим, и угадать его заранее нельзя. Если важно чтобы соединение не рвалось само по себе - придется вводить в протокол клиентские keep-alive сообщения, с настраиваемым интервалом.